# How to add tooltip in the button bar skin

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to add tooltip in the skin of button bar button but not able to do that, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this as well.  I finally settled on adding my tooltips in actionscript rather than messing with skins.  After creation is complete you can do this:

```
var button:ButtonBarButton = myButtonBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as ButtonBarButton;
button.toolTip = "Magic!";
```

Where "i" is the index of the button you want to add the tooltip to.

Hope that helps.